Updating a Microsoft List with Highest Column Values from CSV Without Duplicates
I have a Microsoft List that is updated by Power Automate. When a CSV file is created or modified, the flow is triggered to check whether the corresponding entry already exists. If it does, the flow updates the existing entry; if not, it creates a new entry.
enter image description here
Current Setup:
In my Get Items, I am using the Filter Query: Title eq 'concat(items('Apply_to_each')['X'], '|', items('Apply_to_each')['Y'])'
In my condition, I check if the length of the returned items is greater than zero: length(outputs('Get_items')?['body/value']) is greater than 0
Desired Changes:
I want to modify my flow to update or create entries based on another column (let's call it Column Z). Given the following sample data from my CSV:



Column X
Column Y
Column Z




123456
10
456789


123456
10
456789


123456
10
789456


789456
30
852047



Goal:
I want my flow to create two entries in the Microsoft List, as there are only two unique titles. If an entry already exists, it should update it based on the largest value in Column Z.



Column X
Column Y
Column Z




123456
10
789456


789456
30
852047



I have tried to change the flow as follows:
Initialize Variables

CurrentItemTitle (String)
CurrentDelivery (Integer)
BestItemID (Integer)
BestMatchDelivery (Integer)

Apply to Each (CSV Rows)

Set CurrentItemTitle
Set CurrentDelivery
Get Items
Condition: Check if items exist

If Yes:

Apply to Each (Existing Items)

Condition: Check if Delivery > BestMatchDelivery

If Yes:

Set BestMatchDelivery
Set BestItemID


If No: Do nothing






If No: Do nothing



Condition: Check if BestItemID > 0

If Yes: Update item in the list
If No: Create new item in the list

Question:
Can you please help me to understand what is wrong with this logic?
